# returning an element extracted from a monad; redundant?

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

Are the following two implementations of flatten equivalent for all well-behaved Monads?

```
flatten1 xss = do
    xs <- xss
    x <- xs
    return x

flatten2 xss = do
    xs <- xss
    xs
```

Comment: Yup, 100% identical. You could just import `Control.Monad` and write `join`, or use `xss >>= id`.

Comment: Yes.  `do {  ...; x <- m;  return x }`  is always equal to `do { ...; m }`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they're identical. They're desugared as

```
flatten1 xss =
    xss >>= \xs -> xs >>= \x -> return x

flatten2 xss = do
    xss >>= \xs -> xs
```

The first one is equivalent to

```
xss >>= \xs -> xs >>= return
```

and by the [Right identity monad law](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws) equivalent to

```
xss >>= \xs -> xs
```

Answer (score 5):

In short, yes. To prove it:

You've written:

```
xss >>= (\xs -> xs >>= \x -> return x)
xss >>= (\xs -> xs >>= return) -- eta
```

in the first and

```
xss >>= (\xs -> xs)
xss >>= id
```

according to the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws), `return` is a right identity so that

```
m >>= return === m
```

so we can do

```
xss >>= (\ xs -> xs >>= return )
xss >>= (\ xs -> xs )
xss >>= id
```